# How to get compiler to infer type from user created classes?

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have a class like this:

```
static class TestClass<T>
{
    public static void TestMethod(T t)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there any way to infer the arguments so I could replace this:

```
TestClass<int>.TestMethod(5);
```

With this?

```
TestClass.TestMethod(5);
```

Comment: See this article: [A neat little type inference trick with C#](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/a-neat-little-type-inference-trick-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

Not with the class being generic.  However making only the method static does work:

```
static class TestClass
{
    public static void TestMethod<T>(T t)
    {

    }
}
```

Invoking:

```
TestClass.TestMethod(5);    // TestClass.TestMethod<int>(int t)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to have generic static class (not only generic static methods), you could write smth like a "factory" class for it (I'll call it `MyInvoker`):

```
static class MyClass<T>
{
    static T myT;

    public static void DoWork<T>(T t)
    {
    }
}

static class MyInvoker
{
    public static void DoWork<T>(T t)
    {
        MyClass<T>.DoWork(t);
    }
}
```

Later in your code you can use `MyInvoker` to omit the generics in class name, for example:

```
MyInvoker.DoWork(4);
```

This would make you repeat all methods from the original class in this invoker, so I do not think it's a very good solution. The DRY principle is violated clearly. Of course, one could try to do this through reflection, but it's quite another story with wellknown drawbacks.

---

If your class was non-static, you could use kind of factory methods like this:

```
static class TestClass
{
    public static TestClass<T> GetInstance<T>(T _t)
    {
        return new TestClass<T>(_t);
    }
}

class TestClass<T>
{
    T t;

    public TestClass(T _t)
    {
        this.t = _t;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return t;
        }
    }

    //...        
}
```

And

```
var tc = TestClass.GetInstance(5);
int val = tc.Value; //int TestClass<int>.Value
```